# mod_mime_magic: can't read `/opt/python/current/app/application.py'

Tags: python, apache, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an issue when deploying a flask application to my elastic beanstalk instance where apache is complaining about not being able to read the application file. I read somewhere that this may be a permission issue, but I thought elastic beanstalk would take care of the permissions and apache automatically?

The error log contains multiples of these:

```
[mime_magic:error] [pid 25543] [client <ip>:55005] AH01512: mod_mime_magic: can't read `/opt/python/current/app/application.py'
```

Comment: scroll back in the eb-log and see if the deployment was successful. i also recommend `eb ssh` to the instance to see what's the status of the file beanstalk complains about

Comment: deployment is fine actually, which makes it more confusing. The app runs, it just complains about this. The file itself is owned by root and only readable by root, so if apache runs on a different user that would make sense that it can't access it. However I don't think you are supposed to ssh in to fix these things, as they are gone once the load balancer kicks in?

Comment: right, sshing is only for debug, not fix. so assuming you logged in and made sure the file of that specific path is present, check what user apache runs in. if it isn't root as well then you probably found a beanstalk bug and will need to change the permissions using .ebextensions

Comment: Thanks, seems like the way to go. 
ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)' reveals that the beanstalk spins up lots of httpd processes on the "apache" user, and a single one on the root user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the correspondence it appears to be a beanstalk bug. the deployed application files are readable by root only so the apache server which runs as the user `apache` can't read them.
Alongside emailing aws support with a bug report, I'd suggest a deploy script that fixes the permissions issue:

.ebextensions/patch_permission.config :

```
container_commands:
 patch_permissions:
    command: "chmod -R a+r /opt/python/current/app/*"
```